# AADB2C90304: User journey went into a bad state. Claims exchange with id '' could not be found in orchestration step '2'

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm building a combined SignUp or SignIn Journey which has either local acccount sign in or social provider. I started with the StarterPack for Local And Social Accounts. Some of my applications are not going to have this particular social provider. My first approch was to have an IDP Subjourney which based on a value read from an Azure Table Storage at the start of the journey either only shows the local account option or local account + social IDP. Local Account works good and I can signin or sign up. For the second option I can click my social provider button and sign in. I can also use the username/password field and login with a local account. However the "No Account yet? Signup now!" link which should bring me to the self asserted profile for Local Account with Logon Email technical profile crashes the journey with the error listed in the title.

I already read everything related to this error and tried switching the order in the ProviderSelection segment. GPT4 wasn't able to help. The changes it proposed made it so that clicking on "Sign Up Now" link also started the Social IdP Exchange.

What is strange that in the error it refers to a blank or empty string Claims Exchange Id. I tried disabling my frontend javascript which I thought maybe messes with the buttons. No luck.

I then thought it might be because it's inside of a Subjourney within a Subjourney that invokes based on the values in my table. So I came across this sample, which sounded good and would simplify things a lot: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/idps-filter

I then added the orchestration steps in my main UserJourney, but still the same issue:

The UserJourney looks like this:

```xml
<UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn" DefaultCpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <!--
        Read the client metadata from Azure Table storage -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="ReadClientMetadata" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="CIAM-ReadClientMetadata-REST" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- Get identity providers from OAuth parameter -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="Get-IdentityProvidersList" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Get-IdentityProvidersList" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- START Identitiy Provider Selection Block -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="FacebookExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="MySocialProviderExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- Check if the user has selected to sign in using one of the social providers -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="FacebookExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Facebook-OAUTH" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="MySocialProviderExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="MySocialProvider-OAUTH" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- For social IDP authentication, attempt to find the user account in the directory. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>localAccountAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- Show self-asserted page only if the directory does not have the user account already (i.e. we do not have an objectId). 
          This can only happen when authentication happened using a social IDP. If local account was created or authentication done
          using ESTS in step 2, then an user account must exist in the directory by this time. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-Social" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Social" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when authenticating using ESTS so they can be sent 
          in the token. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- The previous step (SelfAsserted-Social) could have been skipped if there were no attributes to collect 
             from the user. So, in that case, create the user in the directory if one does not already exist 
             (verified using objectId which would be set from the last step if account was created in the directory. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="8" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWrite" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- END Identitiy Provider Selection Block -->
        <!--
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="InvokeSubJourney">
          <JourneyList>
            <Candidate SubJourneyReferenceId="IdPSelection" />
          </JourneyList>
        </OrchestrationStep> -->
        <!--
        If authorization is handled externally from perspective of the app invoke subjourney-->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="9" Type="InvokeSubJourney">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authorization</Value>
              <Value>INTERNAL</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <JourneyList>
            <Candidate SubJourneyReferenceId="ExternalAuthorization" />
          </JourneyList>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="10" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="TrackSignIn" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="CIAM-TrackSignIn-REST" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="11" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>
```